# Call Java default method implementation from C# with Jni4Net

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, jni4net

I use Jni4Net to call Java from C# and it works great, but if make a C# class which implements a Java interface, I can't use default implementations from the Java interface. Is there a solution or workaround to this problem? Or where can I find documentation about JNI that explains how to call default implementations?